# Why Can't I GET 'Tasks' from Microsoft Graph Unified API?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to build an app demo that will create tasks for users in Outlook. I've been trying using the Microsoft Graph API but I cannot GET data about the tasks.

I'm using Postman (google extension app) to send the queries and I am providing a valid access token.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/tasks
```

And the response is:

```
  {
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "Users must consent to all of the following scopes: Group.ReadWrite.All,Tasks.ReadWrite",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "f8595b76-1ad9-4ad3-af52-2e1028f01879",
      "date": "2015-12-08T18:55:02"
    }
  }
}
```

Why can I not access the tasks for my user? In Service Manager (Visual Studio) I checked all permissions.

As a user I allowed the app to have these permissions. I did not 'revoke' permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the Azure Management portal (https://manage.windowsazure.com) to configure the required delegated permissions for your app.

Your request had the following scopes in the token: Calendars.ReadWrite Contacts.ReadWrite Mail.ReadWrite Mail.Send MyFiles.Write User.Read. It didn't have Group.ReadWrite.All and Tasks.ReadWrite scopes required for this API call.

Please also note that the tasks exposed by the Microsoft Graph API are the Office 365 Planner tasks (see https://tasks.office.com) and not the Outlook tasks.

Comment: Why doesn't Tasks show up in services in Visual Studio?

Comment: Is there anyway of getting to the 'Outlook Tasks' if it is not allowed using the Microsoft Graph? Could I pull a task from 365 Planner and post it into the Outlook Tasks? Thanks.

Comment: There is no way to access the Outlook Tasks via any REST API right now.

Could you please briefly describe how you configured your app/got a token via Visual Studio? I don't recognize the process you're referring to.

Comment: I downloaded a solution that uses the office graph api from github and got the token when I ran it in debug mode. I then used the token with Postman. It was just a way for me to try the MS Graph queries to see if I could get at the tasks and other data.

Answer (score 0):

There is a beta version of the outlook see 
Outlook Task REST APi on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/task-rest-operations